# Efficiently remove rows from a Deedle DataFrame

Tags: c#, .net, deedle

What is the most efficient way to remove rows from a Deedle dataframe? As far as I understand, since Deedle is a column-based framework, removing rows is not a natural operation.

I tried the following way:

```
var commonScenarios = firstFrame.RowKeys.Intersect(secondFrame.RowKeys)
var newFirstFrame = firstFrame.Where(row => commonScenarios.Contains(row.Key))
```

But it's quite slow.